# Report entire failing path in Quartus

Tags: fpga, quartus-ii

I am trying to optimize a design that does not meet the constrains.

I know that you can use Timequest Timing Analyzer -> Report Top Failing Paths to report the paths that have negative slack but it will only show the start and end node of the path.

How can I see the entire path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the generated report for "Top Failing Path", and then right click on one of the failing path, as shown in:

[image]

The three "Report ..." options can then generate a report over all the elements in each path.  Selecting the first "Report Worst-Case Path" given the report below:

[image]